# How do I disable RMI in JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, rmi

Due to various RMI exploits out there and the fact that I don't use it anyway, I'd like to disable RMI on my JBoss server at least externally, but I'm not sure how to do this without breaking things.

I've tried disabling the JRMP invoker, which seems to work but the problem is that I'm unable to then start and stop my server because the command:

```
sudo -u $JBOSS_USER $JBOSS_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh -S
```

returns the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: invoker not bound]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.resolveLink(NamingContext.java:1215)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:758)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:351)
    at org.jboss.Shutdown.main(Shutdown.java:214)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: invoker not bound
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:267)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:294)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:153)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:149)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:466)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:707)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:613)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:247)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:223)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:126)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:667)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:351)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.resolveLink(NamingContext.java:1209)
    ... 4 more
```

I don't see the invoker being referenced anywhere else in /path/to/jboss/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml so I'm not sure what other references I would need to remove.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or am I just asking for functionality that's mutually exclusive?

Comment: Why don't you just prevent outside applications from connecting to your server via RMI by blocking the port?

Comment: that would work, but i was hoping for a more elegant solution :-/

Comment: Which version of JBoss are you using?

Comment: You do realise that JRMP isn't the only RMI invoker running in JBoss. You'd also need to remove the pooled and HA implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JBoss 4, there are several references to the RMI invokers in:

```
conf/standardjboss.xml
```

A lot of functions in JBoss make use of RMI, even if your app doesn't. The easiest solution would be to bind JBoss to an address that isn't available remotely:

```
-b 127.0.0.1
```

---

**Update**

If you only want RMI to be bound locally, edit the BindAddress and RmiBindAddress attributes in the jboss-service.xml file:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.naming.NamingService" name="jboss:service=Naming">
    <attribute name="Port">1099</attribute>
    <attribute name="BindAddress">127.0.0.1</attribute>
    <attribute name="RmiPort">1098</attribute>
    <attribute name="RmiBindAddress">127.0.0.1</attribute>
</mbean>
```

Comment: Binding JBoss to localhost doesn't work because I'd like JBoss to still accept requests to the services that I am making public.

Comment: I actually ended up doing this based on your previous answer and had come back to post it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **shutdown.sh** uses RMI to request a shutdown, so when you disabled the JRMPInvoker, you disabled **shutdown.sh**.

One option might be to use an HTTP post to JMXConsole to request the same.

```
>wget --post-data "action=invokeOp&methodIndex=0&name=jboss.system%3Atype%3DServer" \
[--user=admin --password=admin]
http://localhost:18080/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor
```

It seems to work fine.

**=== Update ===**

The **methodIndex** I used in that URL was 0 which is for **shutdown**, but I did observe a couple of issues with that, especially when using the native APR.  Using a methodIndex of 2 (exit) works much more cleanly. In addition, I added wget options for **timeout** and **tries**. The revised version looks like this:

```
wget --timeout=1 --tries=1 \
--post-data "action=invokeOp&methodIndex=2&name=jboss.system%3Atype%3DServer" \ [--user=admin --password=admin]
http://localhost:18080/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor
```

Comment: Works for me.  No telling what else will get screwed up in JBoss by getting rid of RMI so I may abandon it later, but so far so good.

Comment: I ended up running into trouble with our deployer scripts and to be honest, just wanted to be done with this issue, so I gave up on disabling RMI.

Comment: That will be the title of my new book: "How I learned to stop worrying and LOVE the RMI"